# Как в созданном элементе поставить картинку?

Tags: javascript

```
Delete = document.createElement('img')
Delete.getAttribute('https://www.freeiconspng.com/thumbs/x-png/x-png-33.png')
```

Comment: Скорее всего вы имели в виду метод [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) (Первым аргументом выступает название атрибута, а вторым его значение), вы можете узнать о том как работает `getAttribute` [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute).

Answer (score 0):

```js
const img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = 'https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-images/grapefruit-slice-332-332.jpg';
document.body.appendChild(img);
```